# Detect initial device orientation values

Tags: javascript, mobile, device-orientation

I'm trying to manually create a parallax effect of sorts, and so far here's my JavaScript:

```
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
var top = document.getElementById("top");

window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(e) {
  var gamma = e.gamma;
  var beta = e.beta;
  $(bottom).css('left',(gamma/2)+'px').css('top',(beta/2)+'px');
  $(top).css('left',(gamma)+'px').css('top',(beta)+'px');

});
```

So far its working great and I have the effect I want, but the starting position of the device is not quite what I want. Currently the `alpha, beta, and gamma` values are only at `0,0,0` if the device is flat on the table. What I want to do is that when you load the page, that position is taken as `0,0,0`.

For example, if I am reading my phone in my hand, then of course my phone is going to be at an angle already, and I want to take this starting position as `0,0,0` when the page is loaded.

So to put that into some sort of pseudo code, here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
gammaOnLoad and betaOnLoad = initial device orientation

gammaCurrent and betaCurrent = e.gamma and e.beta (from event listener)

gammaDifference and betaDifference = Math.abs(gammaOnLoad - gammaCurrent)

$(elem).css('left', gammaDifference + 'px').css('top', betaDifference + 'px');
```

So essentially you take in the values when loading the page and use those as 0, your point of origin. This means that whatever angle your phone is at, when you load the page the image will always look normal and from there it will begin the parallax effect.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing as you. This is very basic, but it seems to work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var origLR, origFB;

        function setOrigin(eventData) {

            origLR = eventData.gamma;

            origFB = eventData.beta;

        }

        if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {

            window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrigin, false);

            setTimeout(function() {

                window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', setOrigin, false);

                window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(eventData) {

                    var tiltLR = eventData.gamma,

                    tiltFB = eventData.beta;

                    tiltLR = (origLR - tiltLR);
                    tiltFB = (origFB - tiltFB);

                    deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB);

                }, false);
            }, 100);

        };

        function deviceOrientationHandler(tiltLR, tiltFB) {

            $('.bottom').css('transform','translateX(' + (tiltLR/5) + 'px) translateY(' + (tiltFB/5) + 'px)');
            $('.top').css('transform','translateX(' + (tiltLR/2.5) + 'px) translateY(' + (tiltFB/2.5) + 'px)');

        }
    });
```

I added an event listener for 100ms that sets the initial device orientation values, then removed it and replaced it with one that calculates the difference between initial and current.

This can probably be more efficient, I'm not a particularly experienced programmer.

Comment: Worked for me here in 2020. You might have mentioned that the timer (or alternative) is essential because the first reading (at least) can return false zeros. I'm just working on this but even just taking the 2nd reading might work.